# Filter for handled exceptions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have quite large solution and with Web API and Web App with DB, which can be in read-only mode. If it is in read-only mode, every trial to change data will result in exception. What I need is to look at the exception, decide if it is exception alerting read-only database and in case give appropriate message to consumer of app/api. So I need sort of exception filter for filtering exception, but I need to look at all exceptions. Both handled and unhandled, because there is really lot of exception handling in the solution and if I had to implement this functionality catch statement by catch statement, it would be uncomfortable overhead.

So question is: Is possible to create filter for handled exceptions for Web App/Web API?

Thank a lot for advices

Comment: Well you can use multiple catch blocks to catch different kinds of exceptions, and for any unhandled ones you can just catch the generic `System.Exception` and do something with that.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/731913/Exception-Handling-in-MVC

Comment: Do you use a data access layer or ORM?  Which?

Comment: @JohnWu data access layer